# How to disable stopping a bash script from executing after calling some command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, maven

I am trying to create a bash script to deploy an application. Prior to deploying, the application must be built using maven. The problem is, once the maven build finishes, the next command is never called. It seems like maven issues some signal to terminate any further execution.

E.g. in the following script, the `Hello world` is never written to standard output.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec mvn -DskipTests -Darguments=-DskipTests clean install

echo "Hello world"
```

Is there a way how to go around this limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `exec` from your command line calling Maven.

The `exec` command replaces the shell with the command being executed, so the shell is no longer around and won't execute anything after that line (well, except if starting that command fails.)

If you want the shell around, just don't use `exec` for spawning external commands.